# Custom time format in excel

Tags: excel, time

I have formatted some fields in my excel file using `hh:mm:ss` format for time values which outputs - for example - 12 hours and 23 minutes and 13 seconds to `12:23:13`. What I'm looking for, is formatting the given time as: `12h 23m 13s`. I mean I want to add `h` for hours, `m` for minutes, and `s` for seconds to the format. But googling the issue doesn't give me anything. Do you have any idea please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following mask should work for you:

`hh\h mm\m ss\s`

The `\` char forces next character to be treated literally.